# Getting data out of Firebase database in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been bashing my head against a wall with this for about 8 hours solid now and I am desperate, so I hope there is someone out there who has managed to get this stuff working.  Please let there be someone.

The issue is simple, on the face of it.  I have a firebase database that looks like the following:

```
 AppName
   - Profiles
     - UID
       - Name
```

All I want to do is get all the UID and Name values out of the database and pair them up.   I have tried everything I can find online but this is starting to look impossible and I don't understand why.   Here is the issue:

Any attempt to pull data out of the database is all simultaneous.   So I can get the UID of a user, no problem, but there is no way that I can see the Name value, because to get the name value I require the UID value and at the time I request the Name value, the UID is always Null.

Here is the code I am using to get the data out:

```
OnCreate() {
   LoadContactKeys();
   LoadContactNames();
}


private void LoadContactKeys() {
    DatabaseReference contactsList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Profiles").child(ping_userID).child("Contacts");
    contactsList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                contactData[0][0] = String.valueOf(dsp.getKey());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "contact: " + contactData[0][0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private void LoadContactNames() {
    DatabaseReference contactsList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Profiles").child(ping_userID).child("Contacts").child(contactData[0][0]).child("Name");
    contactsList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                contactData[1][0] = String.valueOf(dsp.getKey());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "contact: " + contactData[1][0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried dozens of ways of splitting this up so I can populate the UIDs first so that I can actually use them to get Names, but I cannot find any way that this is possible, everything is always called at the same time and the UID is always null at the time of the Name call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
 ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key=datas.getKey();
            String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
              }
        }
}
```

The datasnapshot is `Profiles`, then using the for loop it will iterate inside the direct children which are the `uid` and you will be able to get the uid using: `String key=datas.getKey();` and the names using `String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();`

Comment: Wow man... it was that easy.   I have legit been tearing my hair out.   Take your upvote you glorious man. +1